# Converting HTML Template to pdf in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, templates, pdf, rendering

I am currently using weasyprint to convert a HTML template to pdf. Now my company has decided to move from python to javascript for increased user experience or something.
Is there a PDF renderer in JavaScript that can do the following:

- Use data on the client. I have data that under no circumstances can be transferred over the internet. (That is the reason I can not create the pdf on backend side or use external renderers.)
- Use CSS page numbering
- Use features like page headers and footers on print medium.
- And of course can do the usual CSS layout.

Ideally there is something that can be used in python and javascript. But Weasyprint works great with python, so I can keep that if there is no "one tool to do the job everywhere".